# Percolation model (counting nodal domains ) hoshen-kopelman algo not getting desired output

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to code a percolation model i am using hoshen-kopelman algorithm in below code the problem is that one the program is counting nodal domains one count get missed and all others preceding are incremented by one automatically from original output in this case the 8 is missing

After this problem I think to introduce backtrace func so it is incomplete sorry for that i want help in that only

```
original output:
1   0   2   2   0   0   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   0
0   0   2   0   0   4   0   0   3   3   3   0   0   0   5
0   2   2   2   2   0   0   0   0   3   0   5   5   5   5
6   0   2   2   0   7   0   0   0   0   5   5   0   0   5
0   0   2   2   0   0   0   0   5   0   0   0   8   0   5
9   0   2   0   10  0   0   0   5   0   0   5   0   5   5
9   9   0   0   10  0   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   0
9   0   0   10  10  10  0   0   5   5   5   0   0   5   5
9   9   0   10  10  10  0   11  0   5   0   0   12  0   0
0   0   13  0   0   10  10  0   5   5   0   12  12  0   0

output that come:
1   0   2   2   0   0   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   0   
0   0   2   0   0   4   0   0   3   3   3   0   0   0   5   
0   2   2   2   2   0   0   0   0   3   0   5   5   5   5   
6   0   2   2   0   7   0   0   0   0   5   5   0   0   5   
0   0   2   2   0   0   0   0   5   0   0   0   9   0   5   
10   0   2   0   11   0   0   0   5   0   0   5   0   5   5   
10   10   0   0   11   0   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   0   
10   0   0   11   11   11   0   0   5   5   5   0   0   5   5   
10   10   0   11   11   11   0   12   0   5   0   0   13   0   0   
0   0   14   0   0   11   11   0   5   5   0   13   13   0   0   
package percolate;

public class Count
{
    int i,j,count=0;
    /*int[][] matrix = {  {1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1},
                        {1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1},
                        {0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0},
                        {1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},
                        {1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0},
                        {0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1},
                        {0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1},
                        {1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0}};*/
    int[][] matrix = {
        {1  ,0  ,1  ,1  ,0  ,0  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,0},
        {0  ,0  ,1  ,0  ,0  ,1  ,0  ,0  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,1},
        {0  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,1  ,0  ,1  ,1  ,1, 1},
        {1  ,0  ,1  ,1  ,0  ,1  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,1  ,1, 0,  0,  1},
        {0  ,0  ,1  ,1  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,1  ,0  ,0, 0,  1,  0,  1},
        {1  ,0  ,1  ,0  ,1  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,1  ,0  ,0  ,1, 0   ,1, 1},
        {1  ,1  ,0  ,0  ,1  ,0  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,1, 1   ,1  ,0},
        {1  ,0  ,0  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,0  ,0  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,0, 0   ,1, 1},
        {1  ,1  ,0  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,0  ,1  ,0  ,1  ,0  ,0  ,1, 0,  0},
        {0  ,0  ,1  ,0  ,0  ,1  ,1  ,0  ,1  ,1  ,0  ,1, 1   ,0, 0},

};
    int row =10,col =15;
int[][] label = new int [row][col];

    private void operation(int i,int j)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(i==0 && j==0)
        {
            count=count+1;
            label[i][j]=count;
        }
        else if (((i-1)>=0) && j==0) 
        {
            left(i,j);  
        }
        else if (((j-1)>=0)&& i==0)
        {
            above(i,j);
        }
        else 
        {
        aboveleft(i,j); 
        }


    }
    private void check() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) 
        {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if(matrix[i][j]==0)
            {
                label[i][j]=matrix[i][j];
            }
            else
            {
                operation(i,j);
            }
        }   
        }

    }
    private void left(int a,int b)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(matrix[a-1][b]!=0)
        {
            label[a][b]=label[a-1][b];
        }
        else
        {
            count=count+1;
            label[a][b]=count;
        }

    }
    private void above(int a,int b) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          if (matrix[a][b-1]!=0)
          {
              label[a][b]=label[a][b-1];
          }
          else
          {
            count=count+1;
            label[a][b]=count;
          }
    }
    private void aboveleft(int a,int b)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (matrix[a][b-1]!=0 && matrix[a-1][b]==0)
        {
            label[a][b]=label[a][b-1];
        }
        else if (matrix[a-1][b]!=0 && matrix[a][b-1]==0)
        {
            label[a][b]=label[a-1][b];
        }
        else if (matrix[a][b-1]==0 && matrix[a-1][b]==0)
        {
            count=count+1;
            label[a][b]=count;
        }
        else
        {
            checklabel(a, b);
        }

    }
    private void checklabel(int a, int b)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(label[a-1][b]>label[a][b-1])
        {
            label[a][b]=label[a][b-1];
            int neww=label[a][b-1];
            int old=label[a-1][b];
            nonzero(old,neww);
            count=count-1;
        }
        else if (label[a-1][b]==label[a][b-1])
        {
            label[a][b]=label[a-1][b];

        }
        else
        {
            label[a][b]=label[a-1][b];
            int neww=label[a-1][b];
            int old=label[a][b-1];
            nonzero(old,neww);
            count=count-1;
        }

    }
    private void nonzero(int ol,int nw)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                if (label[i][j]==ol)
                {
                    label[i][j]=nw;
                    backtrace(i,j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void backtrace(int a,int b)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = a; i < row; i++) 
        {
        for (int j = b; j < col; j++)
        {

        }   
        }

    }
    private void output() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(label[i][j]+"   ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Count a=new Count();
   a.check();
   a.output();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have solved it by coding the function backtrace and by calling it at right place check the code below:-
 package percolate;

```
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;

public class Count
{
    int i,j,count=0;
    int row =4,col =5;
    int[][] label = new int [row][col];
    int[][] matrix = new int [row][col];
    /*int[][] matrix = {  {1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1},
                        {1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1},
                        {0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0},
                        {1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},
                        {1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0},
                        {0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1},
                        {0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1},
                        {1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0}};*/
    /*int[][] matrix = {
        {1  ,0  ,1  ,1  ,0  ,0  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,0},
        {0  ,0  ,1  ,0  ,0  ,1  ,0  ,0  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,1},
        {0  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,1  ,0  ,1  ,1  ,1, 1},
        {1  ,0  ,1  ,1  ,0  ,1  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,1  ,1, 0,  0,  1},
        {0  ,0  ,1  ,1  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,1  ,0  ,0, 0,  1,  0,  1},
        {1  ,0  ,1  ,0  ,1  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,1  ,0  ,0  ,1, 0   ,1, 1},
        {1  ,1  ,0  ,0  ,1  ,0  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,1, 1   ,1  ,0},
        {1  ,0  ,0  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,0  ,0  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,0, 0   ,1, 1},
        {1  ,1  ,0  ,1  ,1  ,1  ,0  ,1  ,0  ,1  ,0  ,0  ,1, 0,  0},
        {0  ,0  ,1  ,0  ,0  ,1  ,1  ,0  ,1  ,1  ,0  ,1, 1   ,0, 0},

};*/



    private void operation(int i,int j)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(i==0 && j==0)
        {
            count=count+1;
            label[i][j]=count;
        }
        else if (((i-1)>=0) && j==0) 
        {
            left(i,j);  
        }
        else if (((j-1)>=0)&& i==0)
        {
            above(i,j);
        }
        else 
        {
        aboveleft(i,j); 
        }


    }
    private void rand() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) 
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
                {
                   matrix[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*2);

                }
            }

    }
    private void check() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) 
        {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if(matrix[i][j]==0)
            {
                label[i][j]=matrix[i][j];
            }
            else
            {
                operation(i,j);
            }
        }   
        }

    }
    private void left(int a,int b)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(matrix[a-1][b]!=0)
        {
            label[a][b]=label[a-1][b];
        }
        else
        {
            count=count+1;
            label[a][b]=count;
        }

    }
    private void above(int a,int b) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          if (matrix[a][b-1]!=0)
          {
              label[a][b]=label[a][b-1];
          }
          else
          {
            count=count+1;
            label[a][b]=count;
          }
    }
    private void aboveleft(int a,int b)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (matrix[a][b-1]!=0 && matrix[a-1][b]==0)
        {
            label[a][b]=label[a][b-1];
        }
        else if (matrix[a-1][b]!=0 && matrix[a][b-1]==0)
        {
            label[a][b]=label[a-1][b];
        }
        else if (matrix[a][b-1]==0 && matrix[a-1][b]==0)
        {
            count=count+1;
            label[a][b]=count;
        }
        else
        {
            checklabel(a, b);
        }

    }
    private void checklabel(int a, int b)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(label[a-1][b]>label[a][b-1])
        {
            label[a][b]=label[a][b-1];
            int neww=label[a][b-1];
            int old=label[a-1][b];
            nonzero(old,neww);
            backtrace(old);
            count=count-1;
        }
        else if (label[a-1][b]==label[a][b-1])
        {
            label[a][b]=label[a-1][b];

        }
        else
        {
            label[a][b]=label[a-1][b];
            int neww=label[a-1][b];
            int old=label[a][b-1];
            nonzero(old,neww);
            backtrace(old);
            count=count-1;
        }

    }
    private void nonzero(int ol,int nw)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                if (label[i][j]==ol)
                {

                    label[i][j]=nw;

                }
            }

        }
    }
    private void backtrace(int a)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) 
        {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if(label[i][j]>a )
            {
                label[i][j]=(label[i][j])-1;
            }
        }   
        }

    }
    private void output() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                if (label[i][j]<10)
                {
                    System.out.print(label[i][j]+"   ");
                }
                else
                System.out.print(label[i][j]+"  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Count a=new Count();
    a.rand();
   a.check();
   a.output();
}
}
```